# Using dollar sign with jQuery in WordPress

Tags: jquery

For code executed after page is fully loaded (not just DOM) I use this function:

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
});
```

But I can't use the `dollar` sign inside, only "jQuery". Is there a way to use the sign instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. In your situation, where you really do want to use `window`'s `load` event, you can simply use a local variable in your event handler:

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
    var $ = jQuery;

    // Use $ here...
});
```

Or you can use an inline-invoked function:

```
(function($) {
    // Use $ here...
    $(window).bind("load", function() {
         // Page is fully loaded now
    });
})(jQuery);
```

...but if **all** of your code is in the `load` handler, I'd probably go with the variable.

---

It doesn't apply to your scenario because you've explicitly said you want to wait for the page to be **fully** loaded (so the `load` event is correct), but for *others* who may find this later who just want to do it when the DOM is ready, there are two other options:

1. Instead of using `window`'s `load` event, use jQuery's `ready` event; the callback receives a reference to `jQuery` as the first argument:

   ```
   jQuery(function($) {
       // Use $ here...
   });
   ```
2. If you control where your `script` tags go, put your `script` tag at the end of the page, and then you don't need `load` **or** `ready`, just an inline-invoked function expression:

   ```
   (function($) {
       // Use $ here...
   })(jQuery);
   ```

Again, those don't apply to you, but perhaps to others finding this later.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder According to me  '$' and 'jQuery' are same OR we can say '$' is an alias of 'jQuery'.

Comment: @RohitArora No because wordpress removes `$` reference, using `jQuery.noConflict();` letting you use other library without too many headhaches

Comment: @RohitArora: Yes, *normally* (e.g., if `noConflict` weren't used by Wordpress), it would be valid to say that `$` is an alias of `jQuery` and vice versa. More formally, they are both global variables created by jQuery that refer to the same function. But as A. Wolff pointed out, once `noConflict` is called, the global `$` doesn't refer to that function anymore. The techniques above use various ways of creating *local* `$` variables/arguments instead, and pointing them at the function.